# Google api and google maps with release apk

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

'Android: cannot use Google API  and cannot show a map for release APK

Everything is ok with debugging app

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved my problem after applying this configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please generate SHA-1 key using keystore and release APK for use below command:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\HoSiLuan.android\debug.jks -list
>   -v